# How to get correct MQTT tcp ? project in Android Studio

Tags: android, tcp, mqtt

Here is my code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        //xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xx is my problem
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xx", MqttClient.generateClientId());           
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.getMessage(); // client is always null
    }
```

what is correct tcp address ?
My computer tcp ? or my phone tcp ? how to get it ?

I try My computer tcp and  my phone ip , but always get "client null "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701670/cant-run-my-mqtt-application-on-android-studio

Comment: sorry, my native language is not english，i need keypoint or keyword to find text

Comment: I paste <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />        still get client null

Comment: It's **Mqtt broker IP**, do you have any thing like **rabbitmq, mosquitto** running ?

Comment: yes, i have mosquitto and it's running , how to get Mqtt broker IP ? what is it ? computer of run mosquitto  (is it computer ip ?)

Comment: Yes, it's the computer that running Mqtt broker + port 1883. etc `192.168.1.23:1883`
You can use [Paho client](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/tool/) to check connection

Comment: i will try it ! before connect success , keep tracking my problem, please.very  very thank you !

Comment: i try it , but still get client null . mosquitto on virtualbox , my win 7 computer connect virtualbox computer by ping ip is ok , whether need set mosquitto .conf or do something .  My virtualbox computer have 192.168.122.1 :53 and 0.0.0.0: 1883 , my code use tcp://192.168.122.1:1883, still fail

Comment: I don't use virtualbox, but I think may be port 1883 is **closed**, so pls try to [forward port](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) and check it again, mosquitto has its test broker, use it [mqtt broker](http://test.mosquitto.org) to check if your code works or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105549/discussion-between-trung-and-user2468652).